# MqttException Android 12

Tags: android, android-studio, mqtt

I'm trying to get MQTT working on Android 12, I imported the aar file and did everything I needed [as here](https://github.com/hannesa2/paho.mqtt.android/releases/tag/3.3.0)
but now I'm getting this error:

```
exception MqttException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
}

 catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MqttException e) {
     ^
```

Errors on the lines:109 123 174

My code is:

```
 package com.example.serverconnectionukaa;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import info.mqtt.android.service.Ack;

import info.mqtt.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class    Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText brokerAddress, textToSend, topicToSend, subscriptionTopic;
    Button connectButton, sendButton, subscribeButton;
    TextView receivedMessage, connectionStatus;

    MqttAndroidClient client;

    String serverURL = "tcp://broker.hivemq.com:1883";
    String topic = "mqtt/topic";
    String sTopic = "mqtt/sensorData";

    boolean connectionFlag = false;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        brokerAddress = findViewById(R.id.broker_address);
        textToSend = findViewById(R.id.text_to_send);
        topicToSend = findViewById(R.id.topic_to_send);
        subscriptionTopic = findViewById(R.id.subscription_topic);
        subscribeButton = findViewById(R.id.subscribe_button);
        connectButton = findViewById(R.id.connect_to_broker_button);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        receivedMessage = findViewById(R.id.received_message);
        connectionStatus = findViewById(R.id.connection_status);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                serverURL = "tcp://" + brokerAddress.getText().toString() + ":1883";
                connectToBroker();
            }
        });
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                topic = topicToSend.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(topic);
            }
        });
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        subscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sTopic = subscriptionTopic.getText().toString();
                subscribeToTopic(sTopic);
            }
        });
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void connectToBroker() {
        String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
        client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), serverURL, clientId, Ack.AUTO_ACK);

        try {
            IMqttToken token = client.connect();
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    connectionStatus.setText("Connected To " + serverURL);
                    connectionFlag = true;
                    sendButton.setEnabled(true);
                    subscribeButton.setEnabled(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void sendMessage(String topic) {
        String payload = textToSend.getText().toString();
        byte[] encodedPayload;
        try {
            encodedPayload = payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(encodedPayload);
            client.publish(topic, message);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void subscribeToTopic(String topic) {
        try {
            if (client.isConnected()) {
                client.subscribe(topic, 0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                        connectionStatus.setText("Connection Failed");
                        connectionFlag = false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                        receivedMessage.setText(message.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (connectionFlag) {
            try {
                IMqttToken disconnectToken = client.disconnect();
                disconnectToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connectionFlag = false;
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

This problem did not exist before I tried to transfer the library, if the script will work back to the normal library, but only up to android 11, on android 12 it will no longer work
How to fix it?

Comment: Did the compiler provide information on the file in which the error was found (along with a line number)? If so please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Edited post as you said. @Brits